# disable vue-cli webpack encoding image base64

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vuejs2, webpack-2

i just try vuejs with webpack template, then i realize every image in my page was encoded with data:image/png;base64 .. with some reason i think i don't want to use that feature

i don't set .htaccess file to encode image to base64, so i think the problem is webpack, but i can't find any webpack file related to base64 image encoding

i unable to figure it out how to disable it, i already try to disable some component i think related with my issue on webpack, but it doesn't help .. do i miss something ?

anyone can help me ?

**webpack.prod.conf.js**

```
var path = require('path')
var utils = require('./utils')
var webpack = require('webpack')
var config = require('../config')
var merge = require('webpack-merge')
var baseWebpackConfig = require('./webpack.base.conf')
var CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')
var OptimizeCSSPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin')

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
  ? require('../config/test.env')
  : config.build.env

var webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  module: {
    rules: utils.styleLoaders({
      sourceMap: config.build.productionSourceMap,
      extract: true
    })
  },
  devtool: config.build.productionSourceMap ? '#source-map' : false,
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: utils.assetsPath('js/[name].[chunkhash].js'),
    chunkFilename: utils.assetsPath('js/[id].[chunkhash].js')
  },
  plugins: [
    // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/workflow/production.html
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': env
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compress: {
        warnings: false
      },
      sourceMap: true
    }),
    // extract css into its own file
    new ExtractTextPlugin({
      filename: utils.assetsPath('css/[name].[contenthash].css')
    }),
    // Compress extracted CSS. We are using this plugin so that possible
    // duplicated CSS from different components can be deduped.
    new OptimizeCSSPlugin({
      cssProcessorOptions: {
        safe: true
      }
    }),
    // generate dist index.html with correct asset hash for caching.
    // you can customize output by editing /index.html
    // see https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing'
        ? 'index.html'
        : config.build.index,
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true,
      minify: {
        removeComments: true,
        collapseWhitespace: true,
        removeAttributeQuotes: true
        // more options:
        // https://github.com/kangax/html-minifier#options-quick-reference
      },
      // necessary to consistently work with multiple chunks via CommonsChunkPlugin
      chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
    }),
    // split vendor js into its own file
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'vendor',
      minChunks: function (module, count) {
        // any required modules inside node_modules are extracted to vendor
        return (
          module.resource &&
          /\.js$/.test(module.resource) &&
          module.resource.indexOf(
            path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')
          ) === 0
        )
      }
    }),
    // extract webpack runtime and module manifest to its own file in order to
    // prevent vendor hash from being updated whenever app bundle is updated
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: 'manifest',
      chunks: ['vendor']
    }),
    // copy custom static assets
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([
      {
        from: path.resolve(__dirname, '../static'),
        to: config.build.assetsSubDirectory,
        ignore: ['.*']
      }
    ])
  ]
})

if (config.build.productionGzip) {
  var CompressionWebpackPlugin = require('compression-webpack-plugin')

  webpackConfig.plugins.push(
    new CompressionWebpackPlugin({
      asset: '[path].gz[query]',
      algorithm: 'gzip',
      test: new RegExp(
        '\\.(' +
        config.build.productionGzipExtensions.join('|') +
        ')$'
      ),
      threshold: 10240,
      minRatio: 0.8
    })
  )
}

if (config.build.bundleAnalyzerReport) {
  var BundleAnalyzerPlugin = require('webpack-bundle-analyzer').BundleAnalyzerPlugin
  webpackConfig.plugins.push(new BundleAnalyzerPlugin())
}

module.exports = webpackConfig
```

**webpack.base.conf**

```
var path = require('path')
var utils = require('./utils')
var config = require('../config')
var vueLoaderConfig = require('./vue-loader.conf')

function resolve (dir) {
  return path.join(__dirname, '..', dir)
}

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: './src/main.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: config.build.assetsRoot,
    filename: '[name].js',
    publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
      ? config.build.assetsPublicPath
      : config.dev.assetsPublicPath
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js',
      '@': resolve('src')
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|vue)$/,
        loader: 'eslint-loader',
        enforce: 'pre',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')],
        options: {
          formatter: require('eslint-friendly-formatter')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader',
        options: vueLoaderConfig
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [resolve('src'), resolve('test')]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        query: {
          limit: 10000,
          name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**vue-loader.conf**

```
var utils = require('./utils')
var config = require('../config')
var isProduction = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'

module.exports = {
  loaders: utils.cssLoaders({
    sourceMap: isProduction
      ? config.build.productionSourceMap
      : config.dev.cssSourceMap,
    extract: isProduction
  })
}
```

**utils.js**

```
var path = require('path')
var config = require('../config')
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin')

exports.assetsPath = function (_path) {
  var assetsSubDirectory = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? config.build.assetsSubDirectory
    : config.dev.assetsSubDirectory
  return path.posix.join(assetsSubDirectory, _path)
}

exports.cssLoaders = function (options) {
  options = options || {}

  var cssLoader = {
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      minimize: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      sourceMap: options.sourceMap
    }
  }

  // generate loader string to be used with extract text plugin
  function generateLoaders (loader, loaderOptions) {
    var loaders = [cssLoader]
    if (loader) {
      loaders.push({
        loader: loader + '-loader',
        options: Object.assign({}, loaderOptions, {
          sourceMap: options.sourceMap
        })
      })
    }

    // Extract CSS when that option is specified
    // (which is the case during production build)
    if (options.extract) {
      return ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
        use: loaders,
        fallback: 'vue-style-loader'
      })
    } else {
      return ['vue-style-loader'].concat(loaders)
    }
  }

  // http://vuejs.github.io/vue-loader/en/configurations/extract-css.html
  return {
    css: generateLoaders(),
    postcss: generateLoaders(),
    less: generateLoaders('less'),
    sass: generateLoaders('sass', { indentedSyntax: true }),
    scss: generateLoaders('sass'),
    stylus: generateLoaders('stylus'),
    styl: generateLoaders('stylus')
  }
}

// Generate loaders for standalone style files (outside of .vue)
exports.styleLoaders = function (options) {
  var output = []
  var loaders = exports.cssLoaders(options)
  for (var extension in loaders) {
    var loader = loaders[extension]
    output.push({
      test: new RegExp('\\.' + extension + '$'),
      use: loader
    })
  }
  return output
}
```

**config.js**

```
// see http://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack for documentation.
var path = require('path')

module.exports = {
  build: {
    env: require('./prod.env'),
    index: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../templates/index.html'),
    assetsRoot: path.resolve(__dirname, '../../public'),
    assetsSubDirectory: 'asset',
    assetsPublicPath: '<?=$path?>',
    productionSourceMap: true,
    // Gzip off by default as many popular static hosts such as
    // Surge or Netlify already gzip all static assets for you.
    // Before setting to `true`, make sure to:
    // npm install --save-dev compression-webpack-plugin
    productionGzip: false,
    productionGzipExtensions: ['js', 'css'],
    // Run the build command with an extra argument to
    // View the bundle analyzer report after build finishes:
    // `npm run build --report`
    // Set to `true` or `false` to always turn it on or off
    bundleAnalyzerReport: process.env.npm_config_report
  },
  dev: {
    env: require('./dev.env'),
    port: 8000,
    autoOpenBrowser: true,
    assetsSubDirectory: 'static',
    assetsPublicPath: '/',
    proxyTable: {},
    // CSS Sourcemaps off by default because relative paths are "buggy"
    // with this option, according to the CSS-Loader README
    // (https://github.com/webpack/css-loader#sourcemaps)
    // In our experience, they generally work as expected,
    // just be aware of this issue when enabling this option.
    cssSourceMap: false
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your webpack related files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to try this line at your json config

```
devtool: (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') ? 'cheap-module-source-map' : '#eval-source-map'
```

Answer (score 15):

Similar to Phil's answer, but without replacing the whole rule, you can use this for Vue CLI 3 in your vue.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
        .rule('images')
        .use('url-loader')
        .loader('url-loader')
        .tap(options => {
            options.limit = -1
            return options
        })
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the `options.limit = -1' does?

Comment: This feature can be disabled by setting limit to a negative number, like -1

Comment: This answer is not valid anymore with Webpack 5 and vue-cli 5.0.1 as it doesn't use `url-loader` anymore but instead relies on webpack asset management

Comment: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'limit' of undefined`

Answer (score 8):

I came across the same issue: some of my images were inlined, and others weren't. It seemed almost random.

It turns out, this is a feature of [url-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader#options), and is not specific to vue-webpack:

`limit: Byte limit to inline files as Data URL`

In the configuration posted in the question (webpack.base.conf), the limit for the url-loader is set at 10kb for images and fonts:

```
 {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    query: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    query: {
      limit: 10000,
      name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    }
  }
```

This feature can be disabled by setting `limit` to a negative number, like `-1`:

```
  {
    test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    query: {
      limit: -1,
      name: utils.assetsPath('img/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    }
  },
  {
    test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
    loader: 'url-loader',
    query: {
      limit: -1,
      name: utils.assetsPath('fonts/[name].[hash:7].[ext]')
    }
  }
```

Comment: it is actually the perfect solution

Answer (score 8):

This is an old thread, but for vue-cli 3 you have to handle it a bit different and maybe someone is searching for exact the same problem.

**vue.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    // clear the existing images module
    const imagesRule = config.module.rule('images');
    imagesRule.uses.clear();

    imagesRule
      // you can set whatever you want or remove this line completely
      .test(/\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp)(\?.*)?$/)
      .use('file-loader')
      .loader('file-loader')
      .tap(options => {
        return {
          ...options,
          limit: -1 // no limit
        };
      })
      .end();
  }
};
```

> All loaders https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/blob/dev/packages/%40vue/cli-service/lib/config/base.js

Answer (score 2):

use this code for Vue CLI 5:

```
// vue.config.js
module.exports = {
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.module
      .rule('images')
        .set('parser', {
          dataUrlCondition: {
            maxSize: -1
          }
        })
  }
}
```