# Why vue.js renders base64 image for small images

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-4

I tried to set image but vuejs automatically convert it to base64 if the image is too small, If I resize the image, it works. Is there any explanation?

Comment: Are you saying you are getting data-uri's for small images? And everything is ok and you just curios about it? If so I would say it is webpack base64-inline-loader module.

Comment: I simply wrote <img src="image url" />

Answer (score 2):

Late reply but answering for people stumbling upon this.

The [`url-loader`](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/url-loader) webpack plugin does this and is included by default. To disable it, simply add this to your `vue.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
    // ...
    chainWebpack: config => {
        config.module
            .rule('images')
            .use('url-loader')
            .loader('url-loader')
            .tap(options => {
                // Do not base64 encode images URLs
                options.limit = -1;
                return options;
            })
    }
}
```

See [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52727581/16863577) on another question.